# Best Practices for long waiting time

Tags: interaction-design, response-time

I am working on a SAAS project.
When the user creates a campaign, the campaign is being created in 4 days.
So is showing them a count down a good idea? and what else do you suggest?
Please give me examples of similar products if you know.

Thanks,

Comment: Would you like to specify what "is being created in 4 days" means?

Comment: Would you from the start know the finish time on the exact second? Otherwise a countdown would not work.

Comment: @JOG unfortunately no it can be less than 4 days, We are creating a software campaign for the users, So sometimes it take 2 business days and sometimes it take 4 days, But not more than 4 days. Currently i am just showing him a message that it will be created in 4 days.

Comment: Aha, it sounds like you are working with an Estimated Time of Arrival, an ETA.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, use some features like google calendar or something else for notify user when the campaign's ready, and for the page that you use your campaigns list show the item as a disable item with a count down, or use a progress bar into the item.
There's some important point you should remember:

- At first: Do not direct user to a page where user's wait for something that takes time for about 192 hours!
- Second: make some trust in your product's interface, like Assuring user for notify theme when their campaign's ready, users won't like to check their panel multiple time a day to see their campaign status.
- Third: make sure your infrastructures are completely ready for notify users and use multiple ways to notify theme (SMS, automated phone call, email and ...).

And at the end, try to making the campaign build up time shorter! :)

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

While I can only guess what it means to be "creating a software campaign", and you don't allow me to put myself in the user's shoes to understand how a user would like to experience that, the only things I can help you with is to remember to

- make it clear that the order will be processed,
- make the ETA clear, and
- notify the user by email or similar as soon as the "campaign" is ready.

If there would be intermediary steps before the ETA, or if there is any interactivity available towards the campaign, that would of course change things.

For better answers, please include more of your work and specific problems into the question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For inspiration, you could check how [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/) deals with maintenance 
issues. On the maintenance page, they post a coding challenge for their developers who can solve it and send it to hackerrank via mail. This ensures that the developers are not disappointed and in fact, creates a very engaged community!